# "error: localhost:xxxxx is not a valid domain" on Facebook Developers application settings

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I am trying to develop an application but I get this error whenever I type in my localhost address into Settings -> Basic -> App Domain field.

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: One does not simply type localhost in Settings. User your IP:port.

Comment: you mean my machine's ip address? thats all?

Comment: Why don't you give it a try...

Comment: hmm okays i ll give it a try..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`App Domain` is where the application resides on production/release, also useful for getting authentication on multiple/sub domains.

You were looking for `Canvas URL` or similar within that section.